# Handling Barcodes/Till in Salesforce

Tags: custom

I am in discussions regarding a potential project using Salesforce.  I am struggling to grasp how we can achieve the following in Salesforce, can anyone advise:

- Print Barcodes from Salesforce onto "Cards" (ive seen "Barcode Zone" in the app exchange)
- Read Barcodes from Cards and integrate into Salesforce (by opening up a Salesforce contact and possibly starting some workflow)
- Introduce shop functionality (scanning items physically, barcodes, stock control etc, opening till drawer and using chip/pin devices)
- Event Management/Room Bookings - displaying calendars etc graphicaly

I am just hoping Salesforce can complete the functionality, I am most concerned about the barcode scanning/printing and chip and pin devices just now.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. It's entirely a matter of creating the interface/controller for each device that reads the data to convert it to Salesforce data. Our DUG did a project with a local Non-profit that read a card scanner to identify volunteers then log them in and out to keep track of the time they volunteered.

Comment: There are many apps/solution available for Salesforce. As already said in previous comment you have to decide based on your requirement.  If you are using mobile devices here is a very good demo explaining this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uORtGgGiFtU.